# Get values from custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom field like this

[image]

I want for each post get "adresse-complete" (sorry it's in French)

Here's my code

```
$type = 'agences';
$args=array(
 'post_type' => $type,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'caller_get_posts'=> 1

 );

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
   <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
   <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'adresse-complete', true) ?></p>
 <?php
 endwhile;
 } wp_reset_query();
```

It displays well the title but not 'adresse-complete'

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What extension you use to manage your custom fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your plaugin/theme uses another customfield-name? It seems that 'adresse-complete' is your slug for that entry. If so, you can find the field-key by using the following code inside your loop:

```
<?php
$customfields = get_post_custom();
foreach ( $customfields as $fieldkey => $fieldvalues ) {
    foreach ( $fieldvalues as $key => $value )
        echo 'Key: ' . $fieldkey . ' , Value: ' . $value . '<br />';
}
?>
```